# VSTO Global exception handler

Tags: wpf, vsto

I have a VSTO application that uses a Windows forms user control to host a WPF form.
I need to implement a global exception handling. 
Tried handling AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException  from the top user control but the function never get called when an exception is raised.

Any guidance Where/How can I implement a global exception handling in this case?

Comment: Is it a VB.NET or C# project?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example in VB.NET of what I use in my projects. I use a class for error handling.

#### Error Handler Class

```
Public Class ErrorHandler

    Public Shared Sub DisplayMessage(ex As Exception)
        Dim sf As New System.Diagnostics.StackFrame(1)
        Dim caller As System.Reflection.MethodBase = sf.GetMethod()
        Dim currentProcedure As String = (caller.Name).Trim()
        Dim errorMessageDescription As String = ex.ToString()
        Dim msg As String = "Contact your system administrator. " + Environment.NewLine
        msg += (Convert.ToString("Procedure: ") & currentProcedure) + Environment.NewLine
        msg += "Description: " + ex.ToString() + Environment.NewLine
        MessageBox.Show(msg, "Unexpected Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

    End Sub

End Class
```

#### Example Of Usage

```
Public Class Ribbon

    Public Sub YourProcedure()
        Try
            'try stuff here...

        Catch ex As Exception
            ErrorHandler.DisplayMessage(ex)

        Finally


        End Try

    End Sub

End Class
```